# Why do I get an access violation when I copy a resource into a Web response?

Tags: delphi, stream, embedded-resource, web-applications

I followed a tutorial [here](http://forum.codecall.net/pascal-delphi-tutorials/35851-store-executable-other-kind-file-inside-your-executable-execute.html) for how to include a file inside of an EXE. While I successfully got a PNG image compiled, when it comes to using it, I'm unsuccessful.

**MyResources.rc**

```
LOGO_PNG RCDATA Resources\Logo.png
```

**MyConsoleUnit.pas**

```
const
  RES_LOGO_PNG = 'LOGO_PNG';

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
{$R 'MyResources.res' 'MyResources.rc'}
```

Now this is where things get a little confusing for me. I have to work with all streams, no files. I have embedded this PNG image `Logo.png` as this resource to be passed back as content (as a stream) when `/Logo.png` is requested from the web server. I also followed a very basic tutorial for this:

```
procedure TMyWebConsole.MyWebConsoleLogoAction(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  RS: TResourceStream;
begin
  RS := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, RES_LOGO_PNG, RT_RCDATA);
  try
    Response.ContentType:= 'image/png';
    RS.SaveToStream(Response.ContentStream);
  finally
    RS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The problem is, when this function is called (at `SaveToStream`) I get an access violation. The web browser on the client end receives the same error message as the content of the "PNG file".

[image: AV]

So why is it doing this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're accessing a null pointer. It's probably `Response.ContentStream`, which is a property you're supposed to *assign*, not *read*. [The documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Setting_the_Response_Content) says this:

> Note: If the value of the *ContentStream* property is not nil, the *Content* property is ignored.

That suggests the ContentStream might be nil. Thus, you need to assign a value to it if you want to use it:

```
Response.ContentStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, RES_LOGO_PNG, RT_RCDATA);
```

The documentation further explains:

> If you use the *ContentStream* property, do not free the stream yourself. The Web response object automatically frees it for you.